# Fancybox fullscreen navigation

Tags: jquery, image, fancybox, fullscreen

I am using fancybox 1.3.4 to show some images. when i click on the div "contentEnlarge" the image will be showed in fullscreen.

```
$('#contentEnlarge').click(function(){
    var original = $('.contentSlider img.active').attr('data-original');
    $.fancybox({
        'autoScale': true,
        'speedIn': 500,
        'speedOut': 300,
        'autoDimensions': true,
        'centerOnScroll': true,
        'href' : original,

    });
```

How do i make it possible to also add navigation in the fullscreen mode?

Comment: since you are calling the image using a "manual" method, the only way to create a gallery is pushing the elements inside the script. I could tell you but you may need to show how your html looks like.

Comment: Did your find any solution or mine's good ?